# can't change ImageIcon from anonymous class inside a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jlist, imageicon

I'm currently building a picture sorter. I have a `JList` which has filenames, to the left of this I have an `ImageIcon` which should show the picture for the current `file_chosen` in the `JList`.

The problem is I can't find a way of updating the `ImageIcon` contained inside a `JLabel`; since the change appears inside the anonymous class where the `ListSelectionListener()` is.

Below is the code:

```
  public class MemeList extends JPanel{


  public MemeList(){
        // load/update the file list.
        updateFileList();

        this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        JPanel east = new JPanel();
        east.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        this.add(east,gbc);

        west = new JPanel();
        west.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        this.add(west,gbc);


            filearray = flist.toArray(new String[flist.size()]);

            list = new JList(filearray);

            list.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener()
            {
              @Override
                 public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e)
                 {
                     if (!e.getValueIsAdjusting())  
                     {

                         file_chosen = (String) list.getSelectedValue();
                         System.out.println("selected = "+file_chosen);

                     } 
                 }


             });


            meme_preview_icon = new ImageIcon(path + "/" + file_chosen); // file_chosen
            label2 = new JLabel("", meme_preview_icon, JLabel.CENTER);
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            west.add(label2,gbc);

                updateIcon();

                JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane();
                pane.getViewport().add(list);
                pane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(320, 340));
                gbc.gridx = 0;
                gbc.gridy = 0;
                gbc.insets = new Insets(0,0,0,0);
                east.add(pane, gbc);


    }
```

Below here is the method for changing `ImageIcon`

```
public void updateIcon(){

    //west.removeAll();

    meme_preview_icon = new ImageIcon(path + "/" + file_chosen); // file_chosen
    label2.setIcon(meme_preview_icon);

    west.revalidate();
    west.repaint();

}
```

Comment: `file_chosen` is not declared in your context.. you are not calling `updateIcon` no where in the code..

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem with my flatmate.

I just needed to call the method `updateIcon()` inside the `ListSelectionListener()`. I got confused because it told me before it had to be static and then the listener can't be static. But there it is.

```
 list.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener()      
          @Override
             public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e)
             {
                 if (!e.getValueIsAdjusting())  
                 {

                     file_chosen = (String) list.getSelectedValue();
                     System.out.println("selected = "+file_chosen);
                     updateIcon();


                 } 
             }


         });
```

Comment: That's not a _static class_; it's an [_anonymous nested class_](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html).